# Python kernel ridge regression: how to know the feature importance for feature selection?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using several regressors to train and test my data in python.

While most regressors in sklearn library have the function feature_importances_ for feature selection, there is no feature_importances_ function in kernel ridge regressor.

How do people see the importance of each feature when using kernel ridge regressor?
I have read the documentation but there is no related information.

Just in case
my code:

```
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge

kr1 = KernelRidge(kernel='rbf', alpha=1.0, gamma=0.01)
kr1.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_kr1 = kr1.predict(X_test)
print("Mean squared error: %.2f" % np.mean((y_kr1 - y_test) ** 2))

# Explained variance score: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Variance score: %.5f' % kr1.score(X_test, y_test))
```

When I tried

```
kr1.feature_importances_
```

The error:

```
'KernelRidge' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature importance is a concept from ensemble learning methods such as [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html); it's not an attribute of a ridge regression model.  The closest counterpart would be a t-statistic, which unfortunately you'll need to compute manually.